# d3.js, mapbox/leaflet and meteor - animations on maps

Tags: d3.js, meteor, leaflet, mapbox

I would like to add an animated line to my the mapbox/leaflet map I have incorporated into my meteor app (something akin to what can be seen here: [D3, Leaflet animation](http://bl.ocks.org/zross/2f2baa1699b8ae38c768)). The aim is to draw a great circle/geodesic arc that connects two points - without using d3, I'm drawing a static arc with the following code:

```
Template.explore.rendered = () ->

  L.mapbox.accessToken = 'ACCESS_TOKEN_MAPBOX'
  map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'MAP_ID', zoomControl: false)
  countryPair = CountryPairs.findOne()
    geojson = {
      'type': 'FeatureCollection'
      'features': [
        {
          'type': 'Feature'
          'geometry':
            'type': 'Point'
            'coordinates': [
              countryPair.country_a_longitude_dec
              countryPair.country_a_latitude_dec
            ]
          'properties':
            'name': 'Country A'
        }
        {
          'type': 'Feature'
          'geometry':
            'type': 'Point'
            'coordinates': [
              countryPair.country_b_longitude_dec
              countryPair.country_b_latitude_dec
            ]
          'properties':
            'name': 'Country B'
        }
      ]
    }
    markerLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer(geojson).addTo(map)

    map.fitBounds markerLayer.getBounds(),
      paddingTopLeft: [
        30
        70
      ]
      paddingBottomRight: [
        600
        30
      ]

    # Code for geodesic
    start = 
      x: countryPair.country_a_longitude_dec
      y: countryPair.country_a_latitude_dec
    end = 
      x: countryPair.country_b_longitude_dec
      y: countryPair.country_b_latitude_dec
    generator = new (arc.GreatCircle)(start, end, name: 'Great Arc')
    line = generator.Arc(100, offset: 10)
    L.geoJson(line.json()).addTo map
```

I have since been attempting to integrate d3 with this code, but have had trouble pulling in the geojson variable. Using the code in the example posted previously (http://bl.ocks.org/zross/2f2baa1699b8ae38c768), I appended the SVG to the leaflet map as follows:

```
Template.explore.rendered = () ->

    # Code as above...
    markerLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer(geojson).addTo(map)

    svg = d3.select(map.getPanes().overlayPane).append('svg')
    g = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'leaflet-zoom-hide')

    d3.json geojson, (error, collection) ->
      transform = d3.geo.transform(point: projectPoint)
      d3path = d3.geo.path().projection(transform)
      lineFeatures = g.selectAll('path').data(collection.features).enter().append('path').attr('class', (d) ->
        d.properties.name
      ).attr('style', 'opacity:0.5')
      # Code continues as in example
```

However, I instead get a type error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'features' of undefined` that fails on this line:

```
lineFeatures = g.selectAll('path').data(collection.features).enter().append('path').attr('class', (d) ->
            d.properties.name
          ).attr('style', 'opacity:0.5')
```

I'm wondering if the d3.json function is being called before the 'geojson' dataset is available, but am struggling to rectify this - any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please don't post your access tokens on the internet.

Comment: Ooops, thanks for noticing!!

Comment: Have you logged the geojson to the console (`console.log(geojson)`)and checked that it's got the structure you want?

Comment: Yes, I've checked - geojson outputs as expected, but thanks for the thought!

Answer (score 1):

this isn't a propper answer but I don't have reputation to comment (weird).

Integrate these two beasts is a really painful task. I've got some result with this [SVG Overlay Layer](https://github.com/teralytics/Leaflet.D3SvgOverlay).

A [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/tTazJeyMrlF0oae2PEX6/preview) to demonstrate. I hope it can be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @jonatas, looks good - I've actually ended up going with a simpler CSS svg animation, but appreciate the guide!